# Retrieve sonarqube 4.4 metrics to excel file

Tags: json, excel, sonarqube, code-metrics

Im trying to use the extract issues excel file from http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Reporting to get some sonar metrics from sonarqube 4.4.

The file retrieves metrics using this web service "/api/issues/search?componentRoots="projectName"&statuses=OPEN&format=xml"

But, in the last version of sonarqube (4.4) this service only responses in json format.

How can I get the metrics with this excel file? Need to recoding vb macro script to parse json? Some similar tool that do the job?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t help you solve this problem but I recommend SourceMeter (https://www.sourcemeter.com/) which calculates lots of metrics, detects code duplications and find coding issues and its output format is csv which can be imported to excel easily. Even more, it has a SonarSube plug-in as well so after installing it you can use it in your SonarQube environment and the csv out is available in this case as well. At that moment, it works only for java.